# Spring reactive @Transactional not working

Tags: spring, reactive, r2dbc

I don't understand why @Transactional doesn't work in reactive. After saving to the repository, I throw an error. But the data still appears in the database.
Spring v 5.3.10

My controller

```
    @GetMapping("/test/save")
    fun saveListNotification(): Flux<Notification> {
        return service.saveListNotification(listOf(
            ...
        ))
    }
```

My service

```
    @Transactional
    fun saveListNotification(listOf: List<Notification>): Flux<Notification> {
        return Flux.fromIterable(listOf)
            .flatMap { notificationRepository.save(it) }
            .doOnNext {
                if (it.rawJsonHash.equals("4")) throw Exception()
            }
    }
```

My repository

```
interface NotificationRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<Notification?, UUID?>
```

Comment: Which database are you using and how have you setup your transaction management. Only adding `@Transactional` in a regular Spring application isn't enough (and your question doesn't mention Spring Boot). Not related, but hurts my eyes, remove the `@Repository` on the interface, it adds nothing.

Comment: postgresql and adding @EnableTransactionManagement. 
Use org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot and **only** use the reactive parts you don't need the `@EnableTransactionManagement`, unless you manually configure parts of it you would even need more.

Comment: with or without it still doesn't work

Comment: Which means you either aren't using Spring Boot or have added manual stuff that is disablilng auto configuration or the thing you are testing isn't even iusing Spring. In short currently there is too little information to help you any further.

Comment: Maybe there is some example of using reactive and @Transactional

Comment: The sample is, create application, add `@Transactional` and run. If you made your configuration more complex then that is probably the issue. But all in all in your current question there is too little information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem
change on the @Transactional(rollbackFor = [Exception::class])
Because @Transactional default will be rolling back on RuntimeException and Error